# How many mangakas use digital or traditional tools to make their manga?

Tags: manga-production

Do mangakas in Japan often make their manga using digital tools such as using a computer, wacom tablet, clip paint studio, etc, over using traditional methods such as using pencil, paper, inking pen, rulers, etc?

What is the most used method to create a manga today in Japan?

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, it is mainly the age of the mangaka that makes a difference: older mangaka stick to the traditional pencil paper, many of them young ones work quite a bit with digital. The rough copy with a pencil and the final drawings will be digital.

Comment: And what are the advantages and disadvantages of making manga the digital way? I know I can say that one advantage is mangakas don't have to buy ink,tones,buy paper thus saving money.I like to hear this explanation from you please

Comment: @DanielRigg I dare say that question is worth its own question there isn't it? (as thematically it differs from the "original" question)